# Z-index of two images relative

Tags: html, css, z-index

I have a small problem which i can't seem to figure out.
I tried searching this problem but i can't seem to find a solid answer.

Look at this example:
[Fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/gDCgQ/)

It's pretty straightforward. I have a div which is centered on the screen.
This div contains an image and i want to put another image on top based on XY positions.
(Normally i get these XY positions from a database but just for the clarity of this example i hardcoded them).

When i run the code my image stands next to my first image. I added the z-index but that doesn't seem to work. I read on some posts about relative z-indexing not working but can someone help me out on how to do this?

Thank you all in advance.
Kind Regards,
Luuk86

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To position an element using  X Y positions you should use `position: absolute;`

If you want to position it inside another element, add `position: relative;` to the container.

Comment: thank you for your reply nmford.

The X Y positions are relative of the div which it has been placed in. I tried adding relative to the containing div but that didn't fix this.

I'm sorry if this is a dumb question but i just can't seem to figure this out. :)

Comment: The fiddle example of Calderan was indeed the thing i was looking for.

Great. Thank you soooo much!